# Is there a way I can use $PATH as defined by my bash profile?

Tags: ssh, shell, path, openssh

I spend most of my day ssh'd into servers. I have a series of aliases/functions/scripts that allow me to type `p hostname` from the terminal and execute GNU screen(1) on the remote side, using the following command:

```
exec ssh hostname -t 'screen -RD'`
```

I've only recently noticed that `ssh -t` does not get my custom `$PATH`. Here's some terminal output:

```
adam@workstation:~:0$ sh server 'echo $PATH'
/home/adam/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/git/bin:/opt/git/libexec/git-core
adam@workstation:~:0$ ssh server -t 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
Connection to uranus.plymouth.edu closed.
```

My biggest problem is my custom aliases only try to execute `screen`, since I can't guarantee an absolute path, and my `$PATH` is structured so the shell should find the correct one. If my `$PATH` settings aren't honored, my scripts don't work. Is there a way I can use `$PATH` as defined by my `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`?

I believe `PermitUserEnvironment` is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the command your aliases use, you can have the remote side create an “interactive”, “login” instance of *bash* (i.e. one that uses your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`) to run *screen*:

```
ssh server -t 'exec bash -ilc "exec screen -RD"'
```

---

If, in addition, you are not getting your normal environment (PATH, shell settings, etc.) in the shells created inside *screen*, you might need to tell *screen* to create “login” shells. Put `shell -bash` in your `.screenrc` on the remote ends, or add `-s -bash` to your *screen* invocation:

```
ssh server -t 'exec bash -ilc "exec screen -RDs -bash"'
```

This will certainly run your `.bash_profile` twice (once before *screen*, once for each shell created inside *screen*). Depending on how you do your PATH manipulations, this may lead to multiple copies of the same additions to your PATH (this is generally not a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Your custom $PATH is probably set in a .bashrc that exits when running under the pseudo-tty environment of `ssh -t ...`.

I don't have any direct experience with this, but I bet if you inspect the .bashrc you'll see it exiting if $PS1 isn't set, or [ -t 1 ] fails, or something like that, before setting the $PATH. And if you experiment, you'll probably find that `ssh server 'try_that_test'` and `ssh server -t 'try_that_test'` give different results.

Probably you can fix it by making the test more complex, to check if you're running under ssh.

Comment: My `.bashrc` sources `.bash_profile`, and the first two lines of `.bash_profile` export `PS1` and `PATH`.

Comment: Curious. Just tested on my machine and `ssh localhost 'echo $PATH'` and `ssh localhost -t 'echo $PATH'` both give me default PATHs. But `ssh localhost` and `ssh localhost -t` both give me a shell with my custom PATHs.

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are only processed for *interactive* shells, which any shell that executes a program such as `screen` (or `echo` in the test cases) is not.  Read up in the bash man page about the `BASH_ENV` environment variable, which can be set up to run a start script for noninteractive shells.

Comment: @Peter, yes I also thought the non-interactiveness of his shell might be responsible. But it's puzzling why he gets the $PATH changed when he does `ssh server 'echo $PATH'` (with no `-t`).

Comment: bashrc is sourced on all shells, both interactive and non-interactive.

Comment: @Rich Homolka: No, I'm afraid you're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `~/.ssh/rc` or `~/.ssh/environment` as well. See the `sshd(8)` man page.